# flask apscheduler start once but run many times

Tags: flask, gunicorn, gevent, apscheduler

I use

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
```

and use apscheduler.BackgroundScheduler()
use gunicorn run flask:

```
gunicorn -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:9999 -k gevent main:app --preload
```

the cronjob start in main.py, it start once, but run 4 times.
if I not use monkey.patch_all(), it run once. Why and how can I use monkey patch and run cronjob once.

I use sse(server-send-event), so I have to use gevent and the monkey patch.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to up (or install) watchdog on your environement.

Personally i don't use monkey, you can try from gevent :

`from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer`

`if __name__ == "__main__":
    http_server = WSGIServer(("0.0.0.0", 5001), app).serve_forever()`

Comment: If I do not use monkey, it will warn me:"MonkeyPatchWarning: Monkey-patching ssl after ssl has already been imported may lead to errors, including RecursionError on Python3.6.....".
And I use gunicorn to run server, will not run into: 'http_server = WSGIServer(("0.0.0.0", 5001), app).serve_forever()' .